# XML Parser is never reached in onCreate

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I've created an XML parser based on the Android docs example found here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

The primary difference between the docs's implementation and my own is I am attempting to implement the XML parser within my Activity - however when I attempt to do so the code does not seem to be reached although it is in onCreate (which I though would start it) I'm not sure exactly what should be done to correct this issue - but any suggestions/input is greatly appreciated.

I've tried moving the closing bracket at the end of my parser however I end up with 84 new errors (mostly duplicate local variable errors - I can provide them if necessary)

I believe I'll need to leave the bracket where it is - and simply call the parser from the android docs example somehow - but I'm not sure exactly how this should be done.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


        // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Read and Parse XML Data from BootConfiguration
        // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public List parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException,
        IOException {
            try {
                XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
                parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                parser.setInput(in, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/BootConfiguration.xml");
                parser.nextTag();
                return readFeed(parser);
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }

        }

        private List readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,
        IOException {
            List entries = new ArrayList();

            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "feed");
            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }
                String name = parser.getName();
                // Starts by looking for the entry tag
                if (name.equals("BootConfiguration")) {
                    entries.add(readEntry(parser));
                } else {
                    skip(parser);
                }
            }
            return entries;
        }

        public static class Entry {
            public final String url;
            public final String user;
            public final String password;

            private Entry(String url, String user, String password) {
                this.url = url;
                this.user = user;
                this.password = password;
            }
        }

        // Parses the contents of an entry. If it encounters a title, summary, or
        // link tag, hands them off
        // to their respective "read" methods for processing. Otherwise, skips the
        // tag.
        private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser)
                throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "BootConfiguration");
            String url = null;
            String user = null;
            String password = null;
            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }
                String name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equals("ServiceUrl")) {
                    url = readUrl(parser);
                } else if (name.equals("ApiUser")) {
                    user = readUser(parser);
                } else if (name.equals("ApiPassword")) {
                    password = readPassword(parser);

                } else {
                    skip(parser);
                }
            }
            return new Entry(url, user, password);
        }

        // Processes title tags in the feed.
        private String readUrl(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
        XmlPullParserException {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "ServiceUrl");
            String url = readText(parser);
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "ServiceUrl");
            return url;
        }

        // Processes title tags in the feed.
        private String readUser(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
        XmlPullParserException {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "ApiUser");
            String user = readText(parser);
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "ApiUser");
            return user;
        }

        // Processes summary tags in the feed.
        private String readPassword(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
        XmlPullParserException {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "ApiPassword");
            String password = readText(parser);
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "ApiPassword");
            return password;
        }

        // For the tags title and summary, extracts their text values.
        private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
        XmlPullParserException {
            String result = "";
            if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                result = parser.getText();
                parser.nextTag();
            }
            return result;
        }

        private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,
        IOException {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            int depth = 1;
            while (depth != 0) {
                switch (parser.next()) {
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    depth--;
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    depth++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // End XML Parser
            // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Where are you calling the parse? I don't see it. What you need do is call the parse method from onCreate and then decide on what needs to be done with the List returned. Obviously, you need to have some UI elements that will show this List.

Comment: You're not calling any of your parse methods so I'm not surprised they are never reached. You need to actually call one in onCreate if you want to use it.

Comment: I understand that... I need help understanding the correct way to call them (this is my first time using an xml parser and I'm very new to this)